# Pycharm docker run configuration do not accept environment variables

Tags: docker, pycharm, environment-variables

I am trying to set up a docker run configuration in Pycharm, i am pretty new to this functionality in pycharm, and i can't get it working. 
In docker I would run the container with the following command

```
docker build -t test-container . && docker run --name container-pycharm -t -i --env-file .env -v $(pwd):/srv/app -p 8080:8080 --rm test-container ./serve-app
```

I set up this in pycharm, by adding the following line

```
--rm --env-file .env -i -t -p 8080:8080 -v $(pwd):/srv/app
```

to `command line options` section in the relevant docker `Run/Debug Configuration` Pycharm window. Unfortunately I get

```
Failed to deploy 'container-pycharm Dockerfile: Dockerfile': com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.BadRequestException: {"message":"create $(pwd): \"$(pwd)\" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only \"[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]\" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path"}
```

Clearly, I cant use `$(pwd)` in my command line options, any idea on how to solve this in pycharm?

Comment: This looks like `$(pwd)` is returning a weird result, have you checked the value of `$(pwd)` in the cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pycharm doesn't invoke docker directly via the command you see in the command preview, it goes through its custom parser, currently they haven't implemented the feature to read envs. Thus "If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path"

And `-v` is not officially supported as command line options in the current version. [Ref](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181088)

Use `Bind mounts` instead

[image]